# Javascript array string as image key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
myArray = [];
```

When a new string is added to the array, I want to draw an image onto my canvas using the string as the image key for example. **Note** there could be up to 20 strings in the array

```
myArray.push("apple");
```

This would then need to run this in order to draw the image onto the canvas:

```
item_apple = game.add.sprite(70, 70, 'apple');
```

The apple string at the end is the string from the array, and it's also the apple after the "item_" at the start.

How can I take the string from my array and use it as an image key when a new item is added. I think I need some loop so each time a string is pushed to the end of the array run the add.sprite using the strings from the new item added to the array.

Comment: Ok, so what's your question?

Comment: Sounds like you want to 'observe' an array. There's a lot of ways to do this, but they're usually dependent on some sort of JS framework. Are you using any type of Javascript framework?

Comment: No not for javascript functions, only Phaser for canvas objects like .add.sprite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to call a method every time an item is added to an array. Assuming you're not relying on a framework like Angular, React or RXjs, `Array.observe` seems like your best bet.

`Array.observe` is a non-standard feature and only supported by Chrome 36 at the moment, so you'll need to [use a polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array.observe) if you need broad browser support.

But basically, it should work like this

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

Array.observe(arr, function(changes) {
  console.log(changes);
});

arr[1] = 'B';
// [{type: 'update', object: <arr>, name: '1', oldValue: 'b'}]

arr[3] = 'd';
// [{type: 'splice', object: <arr>, index: 3, removed: [], addedCount: 1}]

arr.splice(1, 2, 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta');
// [{type: 'splice', object: <arr>, index: 1, removed: ['B', 'c', 'd'], addedCount: 3}]
```

That example was taken form the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/observe)

So in your case, you'll need two variables. An array to hold the strings, and a map (or object) to hold the keys (which I assume is what `game.add.sprite` returns)

```
var myArray = []
var myImages = {}

function addImage(imageString){
    myImages['item_'+imageString] = item_apple = game.add.sprite(70, 70, imageString);
}

Array.observe(myArray, function(changes){
    if( changes.type === 'add' ){
        addImage( changes.object[ changes.object.length -1 ] )
    }
});
```

So the following will result in this

```
myArray.push('apple');

// myArray = ['apple']
// myImages = { item_apple: <Object> }
```

However, I'm not sure how consistent with the proposed `Array.observe` spec the available polyfills are. So your mileage might vary.

However, I think your best bet is to use something like `React.js`. It's perfect for this sort of stuff. If you're not familiar with React, I'd recommend spending a couple of days learning it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it something like below if that is what you are asking:

```
item_apple = game.add.sprite(70, 70, myArray[myArray.length-1]);
```

If the array's length is always `1`, you can give it as myArray[0].